# How to get HTML code which is shown in 'DOM inspector' in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I have tried to understand what is going on while using a 'DOM Inspector' in a web browser (Firefox). I have noticed that the HTML code shown by the inspector is significantly different than the source code of a website.

It occurs only on specific websites as LinkedIn, Facebook, Instagram etc. I've heard something about DOM and know the concept, but...

My goal is to get the code, which is served by the 'DOM Inspector' automatically, for example from a Python script. Here is a HTML code [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yBlp.png) genereted by Firefox.

#### The questions

1. How to download HTML code from the 'DOM Inspector' in a web browser?
2. How can I automatize the process of getting the code evaluated by the 'DOM Inspector' or DOM in general?
3. Is it possible to get the HTML code from a website and evaluate it without a web browser to get full HTML code as it is served by a 'DOM Inspector'?

If you know any frameworks or libraries, which are able to do that, I would be glad if you answer this thread. I am trying to build a Python scraper, but some websites are really unwilling to cooperate with me...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `requests`, `BeautifulSoup`, `Selenium` . https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/

Comment: I know what is webscraping and how to use requests and BS4... But my problem is: How to get HTML code rendered by DOM, not HTML returned by python.requests library or something like that?

Comment: That is what this does. `r = requests.get("https://example.com")
print r.text` ..or maybe someone else can help better. Cheers!

Comment: This will return HTML code from which DOM renders a page and this rendered code I need, not that.
But thanks for help, cuz I found something called MechanicalSoup, which looks promising.

Comment: It uses `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`  . Thanks. https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html